# I'm trying to view multiple models in one view

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm trying to output `item.productname` and `item.price`.

This is my view model:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<SalnAboutu> Aboutus { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SalnWebsite> Websites { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SalnProduct> Products { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SalnContactu> Contactus { get; set; }
}
```

This is my `HomeController`:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;
    private readonly ModelContext _context;

    public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    private List<SalnAboutu> GetAboutus()
    {
        List<SalnAboutu> aboutus = new List<SalnAboutu>();

        return aboutus;
    }

    private List<SalnWebsite> GetWebsites()
    {
        List<SalnWebsite> Website = new List<SalnWebsite>();

        return Website;
    }

    private List<SalnProduct> GetProduct()
    {
        List<SalnProduct> Product = new List<SalnProduct>();

        return Product;
    }

    private List<SalnContactu> GetContactus()
    {
        List<SalnContactu> contactus = new List<SalnContactu>();

        return contactus;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewModel mymodel = new ViewModel();
        mymodel.Aboutus = GetAboutus();
        mymodel.Websites = GetWebsites();
        mymodel.Products = GetProduct();
        mymodel.Contactus = GetContactus();

        return View(mymodel);
    }
}
```

This is the `Index` view:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th>name</th>
    <th>price</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (SalnProduct item in Model.Products)
    {
    <tr>
        <td><p> name: @item.ProductName</p></td>
        <td>@item.Price</td>
      
    </tr>
}
</table>
```

I tried to output the product to see if it will work but there is no output about the model data  only I get to see

```
<th>name</th>
<th>price</th>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZBHR.png)

Comment: The `GetProduct()` method does not populate the `List<SalnProduct> Product` list before opening `Index` view. Populate the collection and then pass it to the view.

Comment: i didn't get the how ?

Comment: If the list is empty, the body of the loop is never executed.

Comment: It seems that your model is wrong!

Comment: i solved it worked like a charm

Answer (score 0):

So my bad i defined a context then didnt assign it  this is how i did it
private readonly ILogger _logger;
private readonly ModelContext _context;

```
    public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger, ModelContext context)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _context = context;
    }
```

And Changed the GetProduct(); to
_context.SalnProducts.ToList();

worked like a charm